# RDP Dynamic Virtual Channels - Creating multiple Listeners

Tags: c++, rdp

I have recently began working with Dynamic Virtual Channels.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/dvc-implementation-details

I have used Static channels for a long time and was able to develop a single plugin that could listen on several channels.

My problem is I am not able to get the Dynamic Virtual Channels to work with multiple listeners. I need to use DVCs to solve some concurrency issues I am having with static channels.

Here is my Initialize method for a single channel:

```c++
HRESULT DVCPlugin::Initialize(__in IWTSVirtualChannelManager *pChannelMgr)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    CComObject<ListenerCallback> *pListenerCallback;
    CComPtr<ListenerCallback> ptrListenerCallback;
    CComPtr<IWTSListener> ptrListener;

    // Create an instance of the DVCPlugin object.
    hr = CComObject<ListenerCallback>::CreateInstance(&pListenerCallback);
    ptrListenerCallback = pListenerCallback;

    // Attach the callback to the endpoint.
    hr = pChannelMgr->CreateListener(
        DVC_CHANNEL,
        0,
        (ListenerCallback*)ptrListenerCallback,
        &ptrListener);

    if (hr == S_OK) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"DVC plugin is enabled!", L"Info...", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"DVC plugin initialize failure!", L"Info...", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

This works perfect for a SINGLE channel. When I try to add additional listeners, only the LAST one will be active. Anyone know how to add an additional channel to the initialize method?

My code is based on this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/dvc-client-plug-in-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to get it to work. It requires a bit more "duplicated-ish" code but it works.

I first needed to create an additional ListenerCallback and ChannelCallback for each channel I want to add. These also come with additional OnNewChannelConnection and OnDataReceived functions for each channel.

The Initialize method then needed to be modified a bit. Likely can be cleaned up more, but works.

```c++
HRESULT DVCPlugin::Initialize(__in IWTSVirtualChannelManager *pChannelMgr)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // chanA
    CComObject<ListenerCallback_chanA> *pListenerCallback_chanA;
    CComPtr<ListenerCallback_chanA> ptrListenerCallback_chanA;
    CComPtr<IWTSListener> ptrListener_chanA;

    // Create an instance of the DVCPlugin object.
    HRESULT hr_chanA = CComObject<ListenerCallback_chanA>::CreateInstance(&pListenerCallback_chanA);
    ptrListenerCallback_chanA = pListenerCallback_chanA;

    // Attach the callback to the endpoint.
    hr_chanA = pChannelMgr->CreateListener(
        DVC_chanA,
        0,
        (ListenerCallback_chanA*)ptrListenerCallback_chanA,
        &ptrListener_chanA);

    if (hr_chanA != S_OK) {
        hr = hr_chanA;
    }

    // chanB
    CComObject<ListenerCallback_chanB> *pListenerCallback_chanB;
    CComPtr<ListenerCallback_chanB> ptrListenerCallback_chanB;
    CComPtr<IWTSListener> ptrListener_chanB;

    // Create an instance of the DVCPlugin object.
    HRESULT hr_chanB = CComObject<ListenerCallback_chanB>::CreateInstance(&pListenerCallback_chanB);
    ptrListenerCallback_chanB = pListenerCallback_chanB;

    hr_chanB = pChannelMgr->CreateListener(
        DVC_chanB,
        0,
        (ListenerCallback_chanB*)ptrListenerCallback_chanB,
        &ptrListener_chanB);

    if (hr_chanB != S_OK) {
        hr = hr_chanB;


    // All listeners created check
    if (hr == S_OK) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"DVC plugin is enabled!", L"Info...", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"DVC plugin is NOT ENABLED!", L"Info...", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
    }

    return hr;
}
```